# como ocultar e mostrar o elemento alterando o css com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

boa noite gostaria de saber como posso esconder e mostrar minha `div` com a `class clic` conforme o `checkbox` selecionado. eu tenho varios `checkbox` e conforme eu selecione ou desselecione o `checkbox` eu quero que ele mostre o elemento e esconde caso eu desselecione. tentei do seguinte jeito:

HTML:

```
<div class="clic" style="display:none"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($(this.checked)) {
    $(this).closest(".hovereffect").find(".clic").css("display", "block");
} else {
    $(this).closest(".hovereffect").find(".clic").css("display", "none");
}
```

com esse codigo eu consigo inserir o elemento mas quando desseleciono o elemento ele teria que esconder novamente a classe clic e ele nao esconde alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem um erro no seu `if`.

ao invés de `if($(this.checked))` use `if(this.checked)`

Ou talvez sua intenção fosse usar o método `is` do jQuery: `$(this).is(':checked')`

Comment: obrigado cara nem tinha visto esse erro era ele mesmo vlw  pela resposta

Comment: Marque a resposta como aceita, por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Sugestão, já com outra resposta aceite...

```js
$('.hovereffect :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest(".hovereffect").find(".clic").toggle(this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hovereffect">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="clic" style="display:none">Olá!</div>
</div>
```

Assim fica mais organizado e usas o `.toggle()` do jQuery.

Se o HTML o permitir até podias fazer isso só com CSS, sem jQuery... assim:

```css
input:checked + .clic {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="hovereffect">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="clic" style="display:none">Olá!</div>
</div>
```